# Remaking TikTok's comments UI: Sticky EditText at the bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

**Problem:** I am trying to remake TikTok's comments UI using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and a `RecyclerView`.

This is how it looks like (ORIGINAL):

[image]

This is what I have tried for now: Basically, I have a FrameLayour whose first child contains eveerything other than the EditText and the second child is, of course, the EditText.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_of_comments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:text="30.8k comments"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/darkGreyText" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_comment"
                android:id="@+id/comments_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
       >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
            android:hint="Leave a comment"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/bleh"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Note that I have a fixed size ScrollView so that the edittext is always visible on the screen. If I remove that, the EditText only becomes visible when the bottomsheet is full screen.

Problem: The problem now is, that the edittext sits on top of the recylcer view at all times. That is what I want, but it introduced a new problem: After scrolling to the bottom of the list (recylcerview), the last item is not completely visible as it is hidden by the EditText.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just add a padding to the bottom of the RecyclerView so that it stays on top of the `EditText`, so the last element won't be covered?

Comment: @jackz314 Perfect. Feel free to add that as an answer!

Comment: I just did. Check if that's what you are going for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a padding to the bottom of your `RecyclerView` so that it always stays on top of the `EditText`. This way, the `EditText` appears "sticky" and the `RecyclerView` won't be covered by `EditText`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use linear layout as root and apply weight to recycle view.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/no_of_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="30.8k comments"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGreyText" />



        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_comment"
            android:id="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"         
            android:layout_height="0dp" />




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
   >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
        android:hint="Leave a comment"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bleh"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        />

   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Abhishek Soni have you tried as an above my answer?

Comment: @Abhishek Soni if my answer is helpful to you, then you can upvote and accept my answer so this will helpful for the other which have the same problem.